# Android app crashes when I create instance for a java class

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I was doing the update operation in Firebasae and im getting this error
here's the code

```
List<Student> studentsList;
        mylistview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int i, long id) {
                Student students = studentsList.get(i);
                showupdatedialogue(students.getName(),students.getName() );
                return false;
            }
        });
```

> Student students = studentsList.get(i); //line

App crashes on this line, "Student" is a java class

Student.java

```
package com.example.login;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class Student {
    String name;
    String roll_no;
    String date_of_birth;
    String class_section;
    String class_teacher;


    public Student(String name, String roll_no, String date_of_birth, String class_section, String class_teacher) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll_no = roll_no;
        this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
        this.class_section = class_section;
        this.class_teacher = class_teacher;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getroll_no() {
        return roll_no;
    }

    public String getdate_of_birth() {
        return date_of_birth;
    }

    public String getclass_section() {
        return class_section;
    }

    public String getclass_teacher() {
        return class_teacher;
    }
}
```

and I get this error, this says the size of the list is 0 but I have items in the list

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.login, PID: 18486
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.login.MainActivity$5.onItemLongClick(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3291)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3206)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18486 SIG: 9
```

Comment: _"this says the size of the list is 0 but I have items in the list"_ No you don't. What in your code should put anything into `studentsList`?

Comment: I am doing CRUD operation with firebase and to create records I use Student.java to pass parameters and insert new records and  I am displaying out the data in a list view when I long press a list item I should be able to edit/delete the records for the list item I long pressed, here `studentList` is a array list for the Student.javaand i want to get the data record of item list what I long pressed

Comment: Nothing in the code given in the question writes anything to the `studentsList`. If some other code somewhere is supposed to do that I'd focus on that and add the relevant part of that code to the question.